# How to fix: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined" in NodeJS (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript

I have a Problem with my code. I try to find an Element in an Array with the following Code

```
Name()
{
    console.log(LoadItems.ItemConfigs);
    var ItemConfig = LoadItems.ItemConfigs.find(itemconf => itemconf.Id === this.ConfigId);    
    if(ItemConfig != undefined){
        return ItemConfig.Name;
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

But it shows me the Error mentioned in the Title every Time. As you can see I've printed out the Array in the Console before for debugging, it gives me many Objects like this:

```
ItemConfig {
Id: 25,
Name: 'Accessories',
Category: 'ITEM_CLOTH_ACC',
Density: 0,
Weight: 0,
Value1: '7',
Value2: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
Value3: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
Value4: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
Value5: 'NO_VALUE_SET' },
```

I dont know why I get this error even if the program knows the Objects. The exact error I get is the following:

```
Invalid argument: expected Number/opt/gameserver/packages/yeet/Models/Item.js:53: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined
    var ItemConfig = LoadItems.ItemConfigs.find(itemconf => itemconf.Id == this.ConfigId);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have this structure for `LoadItems.ItemConfigs` dont have problem. but maybe `LoadItems.ItemConfigs` dose not have this structure

```js
var LoadItems = {};
var ConfigId = 20;


LoadItems.ItemConfigs = [{
  Id: 20,
  Name: 'test_Accessories',
  Category: 'ITEM_CLOTH_ACC',
  Density: 0,
  Weight: 0,
  Value1: '7',
  Value2: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value3: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value4: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value5: 'NO_VALUE_SET' },{
  Id: 25,
  Name: 'Accessories',
  Category: 'ITEM_CLOTH_ACC',
  Density: 0,
  Weight: 0,
  Value1: '7',
  Value2: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value3: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value4: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
  Value5: 'NO_VALUE_SET' }]

function Name()
{
    console.log(LoadItems.ItemConfigs);
    var ItemConfig = LoadItems.ItemConfigs.find(itemconf => itemconf.Id === this.ConfigId);    
    if(ItemConfig != undefined){
        return ItemConfig.Name;
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

console.log(Name());
```

Comment: Its the Same structure, but it starts with <1 empty item>, but i dont know why there is an empty item, but then it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the code you have posted, seems, you are doing nothing wrong.
I quickly tried reproducing your issue and seems working fine ( As you can see in the below snippet). Please check your code against mine and see, if you can spot the issue.

> Remove all empty objects from your array to be at safe side

```js
let ConfigId = 25;
let LoadItems = {
    ItemConfigs: Array()
};
LoadItems.ItemConfigs = [{},{
        Id: 25,
        Name: 'Accessories',
        Category: 'ITEM_CLOTH_ACC',
        Density: 0,
        Weight: 0,
        Value1: '7',
        Value2: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
        Value3: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
        Value4: 'NO_VALUE_SET',
        Value5: 'NO_VALUE_SET'
    },{},{}];


//Remove empty objects from the object array
 LoadItems.ItemConfigs = LoadItems.ItemConfigs.filter(item=> Object.keys(item).length !== 0);
function Name() {
    console.log(LoadItems.ItemConfigs);
    var ItemConfig = LoadItems.ItemConfigs.find(itemconf => itemconf.Id === ConfigId);
    if (ItemConfig != undefined) {
        return ItemConfig.Name;
    }
    else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
;
console.log(Name());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've found the Problem already (i think so at least). It is because the first item of the array seems to be an empty item, i dont know why it is there but i try to figure it out.

Comment: you need to remove all the empty objects  in the array. No side-effect of doing so. I have updated my answer as well.